# Change column editor type without changing filter editor type in GridControl

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have the following GridColumn defined:

```
new GridColumn{
    Visible = true,
    FieldName = "blah",
    Name = "blah",
    ColumnEdit = new RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit{
        DisplayMember = "Name",
        ValueMember = "Id",
        DataSource = ViewModel.Components
    }
}
```

This works fine and changes the editor of my `blah` column to a the correct editor, but it also has an unwanted side-effect of changing the `AutoFilterRow` editor for that column to that same `GridLookUpEdit`.  I want the filter to be just a regular text edit field.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set [`GridColumn.FilterMode`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsGridColumn_FilterModetopic) property to [`ColumnFilterMode.DisplayText`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraGridColumnFilterModeEnumtopic) value, it will allow filter values in your column by its `DisplayText`, so the field editor in `AutoFilterRow` will be changed to regular text editor:

```
new GridColumn {
    Visible = true,
    FieldName = "blah",
    Name = "blah",
    FilterMode = ColumnFilterMode.DisplayText, //<= filter mode
    ColumnEdit = new RepositoryItemGridLookUpEdit{
        DisplayMember = "Name",
        ValueMember = "Id",
        DataSource = ViewModel.Components
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted!  The documentation just leads you to believe  that option controls if you're searching by the display member or value member, but nothing about what type of editor the filter has..