# TextBox header filter for all the lookup type columns in Xtragrid

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I use a `XtraGrid` which has a lookup type column. Currently the filter header for this column is a lookup. I want to change this filter to a **textbox**.

****EDIT****

I want this to happen to all the lookup columns in all grids, not just to a specific column.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean that the filter button displays a combo box list, like in this image?

https://documentation.devexpress.com/HelpResource.ashx?help=WindowsForms&document=img3061.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change column editor type without changing filter editor type in GridControl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31149469/change-column-editor-type-without-changing-filter-editor-type-in-gridcontrol)

Comment: @Brendon yes, I want it to be a textbox instead of combobox

Comment: @nempoBu4 Thank you

Comment: Have you considered using the [Auto Filter Row](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1428) instead?

Comment: @nempoBu4 I want this to happen to all the grids and all the columns , not just to a specific column. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @HosseinPanahloo You can use `foreach` loop.

Comment: @nempoBu4 Thanks foreach worked.